# Bad performance of sorting algorithms implemented

Tags: python, sorting

I have implemented some sorting algorithms including Insertion, Selection, Shell, two kinds of Merge. I found that the performance of my implements didn't accord with the description of Algorithms(4th). 
For example, here are two kinds of Merge sorting. When sorting a list contains 100,000 elements, Merge1 takes about 0.6s, and Merge2 takes about 50+s. But Merge2 is almost the same as the one in Algorithms(4th) except I use python. I can't figure it out why Merge2 is so slow and how to improve it. Can somebody help me? Thanks!

```py
class Merge1:
    def merge(self, a, b):
        i = 0; j = 0
        res = []
        while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
            if a[i] < b[j]:
                res.append(a[i])
                i = i + 1
            else:
                res.append(b[j])
                j = j + 1
        res = res + a[i:] +  b[j:]
        return res

    def sort(self, source):
        if len(source) <= 1:
            return source
        half = len(source) // 2
        left = self.sort(source[:half])
        right = self.sort(source[half:])
        retval = self.merge(left, right)
        return retval

    def is_sort(self, source):
        length = len(source)
        for i in range(0, length-1):
            if source[i] > source[i+1]:
                return False
        return True

class Merge2:
    def merge(self, source, lo, mid ,hi):
        i = lo
        j = mid + 1
        aux = source[:]
        k = lo
        while k <= hi:
            if i > mid:
                source[k] = aux[j]
                j = j + 1
            elif j > hi:
                source[k] = aux[i]
                i = i + 1
            elif aux[i] < aux[j]:
                source[k] = aux[i]
                i = i + 1
            else:
                source[k] = aux[j]
                j = j + 1
            k = k+1

    def sort(self, source):
        sz = 1
        N = len(source)
        while sz < N:
            for lo in range(0, N-sz, sz+sz):
                # pdb.set_trace()
                self.merge(source, lo, lo+sz-1, min(lo+sz+sz-1, N-1))
            sz = sz + sz

    def is_sort(self, source):
        length = len(source)
        for i in range(0, length-1):
            if source[i] > source[i+1]:
                return False
        return True
```

Here is the implement in Algorithms:
[image]

[image]

Here is the test code:

```py
    merge1 = Merge1()
    source = np.random.randint(100000, size=100000).tolist()
    start = time.time()
    merge1.sort(source)
    end = time.time()
    print("Merge1 takes: {}s".format(end-start))


    merge2 = Merge2()
    source = np.random.randint(100000, size=100000).tolist()
    start = time.time()
    merge2.sort(source)
    end = time.time()
    print("Merge2 takes: {}s".format(end-start))
```

result:
E:>python sort.py
Merge1 takes: 0.6376256942749023s
Merge2 takes: 57.99568271636963s

Comment: Without going into the details of the algorithms, what immediately stands out is that `Merge1` simply constructs a list with `append`, while `Merge2` is modifying an existing list one element at a time, while also accessing lists for comparisons more often - I figure that's a major part of the explanation. `Merge2` doesn't seem very optimised compared to `Merge1` altogether.

Comment: One thing jumped into my eye. In merge2 aux is always filled with a copy of the whole array, although only a small range is really used of this copy. That might create a lot of copy- and garbage collection overhead. Maybe you can consider maintaining a full copy during the whole operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this modification. According to my quick tests, it improved the performance considerably (from nearly one minute down to less than 1 second). The main performance gain comes from avoiding to create that many copies of the whole list. The other alterations only increase performance marginally.
According to a simple comparison of the sum it should not mess up the list, but you should do some more tests if you like to use it.

```
class Merge4:
    def merge(self, source, aux, lo, mid ,hi):
        i = lo
        j = mid + 1
        a_j= aux[j]
        a_i= aux[i]
        k = lo
        while k <= hi:
            if i > mid:
                source[k] = a_j
                j += 1
                a_j= aux[j]
            elif j > hi:
                source[k] = a_i
                i += 1
                a_i= aux[i]
            elif a_i < a_j:
                source[k] = a_i
                i += 1
                a_i= aux[i]
            else:
                source[k] = a_j
                j += 1
                a_j= aux[j]
            k += 1
        # update the aux array for the next call
        aux[lo:hi+1]= source[lo:hi+1]

    def sort(self, source):
        sz = 1
        N = len(source)
        while sz < N:
            sz_2= sz * 2
            # create the aux array, that will be maintained continuously
            # and add one extra None, so the "prefetching" works also
            # during the last iteration (refering to a_i and a_j)
            aux= source[:]
            aux.append(None)
            for lo in range(0, N-sz, sz_2):
                # pdb.set_trace()
                self.merge(source, aux, lo, lo+sz-1, min(lo+sz_2-1, N-1))
            sz = sz_2

    def is_sort(self, source):
        length = len(source)
        for i in range(0, length-1):
            if source[i] > source[i+1]:
                return False
        return True
```